# What is wrong with "compress" option?

Tags: macos, finder, compression

In finder, I can cntrl + click on a file and click "compress"... Sometimes. It seems that randomly the option just won't show up and I have to open a new finder window, or duplicate the folder first, or something ridiculous like that.

Is this a bug, or is compress only supposed to show up under certain circumstances?

Comment: Also check that the disk has space enough to store the zip file

Answer (score 1):

This might help:

[Apple discussions](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5012526?answerId=29202093022#29202093022)

It says that you can't compress certain folders like smart folders that are created in the 'All My Files' and 'Recents' box.

Answer (score 1):

Open the Terminal.
Use one of the following commands:

```
zip -r name_of_the_archive.zip path_to_the_folder
tar -zcvf name_of_the_archive.tar.gz path_to_the_folder
```